# Show the selected items even after navigating to another page using JQGrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid with valid data.Rows can be selected and on click of a button it is saved.After navigating from this page when I return to this page ,all the selected items should be checked.Is there any method to retain the checks or selected items after navigation?

Comment: I also answered this here ...

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982973/jqgrid-multiselect-checked-box-persist-when-move-to-the-next-page/8162365#8162365][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982973/jqgrid-multiselect-checked-box-persist-when-move-to-the-next-page/8162365#8162365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haven't used the plugin personally but these links might help you

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/JQGridState

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/Save%20state

Comment: Thanks for the links,it was useful. Also i wanted to know if row ID is passed to a function it should show the whole row in the grid to be selected(multiselect set as true).

Comment: @ChemicalX as i said i never used jqGrid so i dont really know much about it :)